# Add standard Google search to map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have built a google map but would like to add your standard google search box so I can do something like type shopping and it will show markers of local shopping stores.

I have been searching on how to do this but most results are talking about using a specific address and geocoding it. This is not what I want.

This is
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=google+maps&rlz=1C1CHMO_enUS519US519&aq=f&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&sa=N&tab=wl

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for:
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/control-googlebar

Here are API examples that may also help:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/

Comment: The "Google Bar" example you link to is the [Google Maps API v2 which is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference) and not recommended for new code (it is very near end of life).